# Autocomplete Textbox in C# and MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

Hi to all and thanks for your help,

I need to autocomplete a textbox with suggestions in C# and MVC.

The textbox in the view is:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="margin-top:2%;">
   <input type="text" class="formLocator" value="Milano" data-date-end-date="0d" id="textLocator" name="searchstring">
   <h4 class="FormTextLocator">Where</h4>
</div>
<div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:2%;">
   <input type="text" class="formLocator" value="Milano" data-date-end-date="0d" id="textLocator" name="searchstring">
   <h4 class="FormTextLocator">Where</h4>
</div>
```

I have created a javascript code for this textbox:

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#textLocator").autocomplete(
    {
        source: "/Home/AutocompleteSuggestions",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) 
        {
            if (ui.item) 
            {
                $("#textLocator").val(ui.item.value);
                $("form").submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And the controller associated is:

```
 public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string searchstring)
 {
     var db = new TocFruit();
     var suggestions = from s in db.city select s.name;
     var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToString().StartsWith(searchstring.ToLower()));
     return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

But all of this doesn't work but i don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks to all,

Roberto

Comment: what issue/error are you getting?

Comment: you have 2 text box with same id?

Comment: i have resolved the double id. The problem is that i don't show the result suggestions under the textbox. I have added the new code. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jquery UI AutoComplete in MVC](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html)

Check the above link

Also Point to Mention as per your Code you have 2 TextBox with same `id`

Comment: Nice tutorial link :)

Answer (score 0):

ok. With your help now the controller return the correct list of value, but the textbox don't show the values. The new code is so written:

Now the code is so written:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textLocator").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/AutocompleteSuggestions",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.name, value: item.name };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="margin-top:2%;">
   <input type="text" class="formLocator" value="Milano" data-date-end-date="0d" id="textLocator" name="searchstring">
   <h4 class="FormTextLocator">dove</h4>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string term)
{
   var db = new TocFruit();
   var suggestions = from s in db.city select s.name;
   var namelist = suggestions.Where(n => n.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower()));
   return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: did you checked the link?